# What is the Delphi unit hashcode used for?

Tags: delphi

Portable executables compiled using Delphi have a `PACKAGEINFO` resource that lists the units the program requires & contains.

Documentation of the structure can be found in this version of [SysUtils.pas](https://github.com/Fr0sT-Brutal/Delphi_MiniRTL/blob/97ed1ce35a16b66ae5addababffd7464367fecfa/SysUtils.pas#L20087), which shows each `TUnitName` entry is:

- One byte containing flags.
- One byte which is a hash code.
- The name of the unit, as a null terminated string.

An example can be seen in the `PACKAGEINFO` structure below:

```
00000000  00 00 10 cc 00 00 00 00 81 00 00 00 01 59 46 6f  |...Ì.........YFo|
00000010  72 6d 31 33 00 10 6d 62 73 55 74 69 6c 73 00 10  |rm13..mbsUtils..|
00000020  55 54 79 70 65 73 00 00 81 53 79 73 49 6e 69 74  |UTypes...SysInit|
```

The first unit defined (after the header) is named `YForm13` with a hash code of `0x59`.  The second is `bsUtils` with a hash code of `0x6D`.

A comparison between different Delphi compiled executables shows that units like `SysInit` and `System` seem to have the same hash code across two files, but this is not a large study.

What is this hash code used for?  Can it be correlated to other parts of the compiled executable?

Comment: Delphi units are versioned. Compiled units depend on specific versions of other units. When a unit is modified and recompiled, it causes versioning errors ("Unit X was compiled with a different version of unit Y") if units dependant on it are not also recompiled. My guess is the hash code is related to that mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hash code is used to check whether or not the units are good and can be loaded. Inspecting the code, it is used at runtime and not at compile time.

The part is not documented, however you may inspect the VCL Source code (which cannot be posted here): unit `System.SysUtils`, look for `InternalUnitCheck`.
The module name will is used as a part of the hash, and the unit name is used as the last part.